# How to create a direct 'pin-it' link for Pinterest on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to include a 'share' button for Pinterest on my blog, much like a Facebook or Twitter share button, which you ordinarily find in the post-footer of most blogposts nowadays.

I've done some research and have come across the following coding:

```
<a class='pint-er-est' href='javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement(&apos;script&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;,&apos;text/javascript&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;charset&apos;,&apos;UTF-8&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;,&apos;http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=&apos;+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());'>Share to Pinterest</a>
```

This is an unofficial 'Share Button' for Pinterest. And it is currently available to see on my blog.

It is ideal for my blog as I can chose a custom/self-designed social media icon to accompany this code so that the overall appearance of the share button fits well with the rest of my blog design.

The issue I have with this piece of coding is that the 'share-button' doesn't automatically pick the first image of the stated blogpost but instead it gives the reader an option to chose amongst all the images available on the entire blog, which includes the social media icons themselves. I would like a share button that automatically picks the first image of the blogpost and opens the image up into the reader's Pinterest account ready for them to add a caption and/or to Pin-It.

I've tried numerous times to try and alter the coding to fit my preferences but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There's a resource from the Pinterest for developers page [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it).  Basically, the code provided from Pinterest allows you to specify the URL, image and description for the user to pin.

Here's the code that you would include in your html:

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
    ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F
    &media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg
    &description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest"
    data-pin-do="buttonPin"
    data-pin-config="above">
    <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
```

Include this in the line before your closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```